# Pagination with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm new to Jekyll, and I'm trying to do some pagination, I am staring with blogs then other collections.

Here's the generated `_site\blogs\index.html` [Source](https://github.com/cyberquarks/jekyll-pagination-demo/blob/main/_site/blogs/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Simple Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Blogs -->

    <div class="pagination">

        <span class="prev">Previous</span>

        <span class="page_number">Page:  of </span>

        <span class="next">Next</span>

    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 My Simple Website. All rights reserved.</p>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

As can be seen the blogs where not generated/rendered.

Here are my project setup:

`\Gemfile`

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 4.3.2"
# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima", "~> 2.5"

# If you want to use GitHub Pages, remove the "gem "jekyll"" above and
# uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
# gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.17.0"
  gem "jekyll-sass-converter", "~> 3.0.0"
  gem "jekyll-watch", "~> 2.2.1"
  gem "jekyll-seo-tag", "~> 2.8.0"
  gem 'octopress-paginate'
end
```

`\_config.yml`

```
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - octopress-paginate

exclude:
  - Gemfile
  - Gemfile.lock

paginate: 5
paginate_path: "/page:num/"

pagination:
  enabled: true
  collection: 'blogs'

collections:
  blogs:
    output: true
    permalink: /:collection/:slug/
```

`\pages\blogs.md`

```
---
layout: blogs
title: Blogs
permalink: /blogs/
pagination:
  enabled: true
  collection: blogs
---

{% for blog in paginator.posts %}
    <div>
        <a href="{{ blog.permalink }}">
            <h3>{{ blog.title }}</h3>
        </a>
        <div>{{ blog.description }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% include pagination.html %}
```

`_layouts\blogs.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    {% include head.html %}

    <body>

        <!-- Blogs -->
    
        {{ content }}

        {% include footer.html %}

    </body>

</html>
```

What could be wrong in my setup?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the default `_posts` collection for blog posts?

Comment: I'm planning to paginate not just blogs post but also other collections, though, I have tried to swap `_blogs` to `_posts` it still did not work

Comment: I don't know octopress-paginate, I'm afraid; I'm using https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2 to paginate multiple collections